# MUI GridActionsCellItem as prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I created a ListView component for my admin page which is responsible for showing, editing and deleting data. I would like to add extra features for some of the pages. I'm using the MUI DataGrid component.

In the ListView DataGrid I have the "actions" column:

```
field: "manage",
    headerName: "Manage",
    sortable: false,
    type: "actions",
    getActions: (params) => [
    <GridActionsCellItem
        icon={<DeleteIcon/>}
        onClick={() => {
            setCurrent(params.row["id"])
            setDeletePopupOpen(true)
        }}
        label="Törlés"
        showInMenu={true}
    />,
    <GridActionsCellItem
        icon={<EditIcon/>}
        onClick={() => {
            setCurrent(params.row["id"])
            setEditPopupOpen(true)
        }}
        label="Szerkesztés"
        showInMenu={true}
    />
],
```

For example from the reservations page I would like to add an extra GridActionsCellItem so I added this to the `getActions` list:

```
extraColActions.map(action =>
    <GridActionsCellItem
        icon={action.icon}
        onClick={() => {action.onClick(params.row['id'])}}
        label={action.label}
        showInMenu={true}
    />)
```

Now I have these two errors:

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'showInMenu')
- The above error occurred in the  component

The `extraColActions` is a prop to the ListView component, and I need that because I want to use the params variable to keep track of the row I click.

From the parent (reservations) component I have this list:

```
const extraColActions = [
    {
        icon: <CheckIcon/>,
        onClick: (id) => {
            // setAcceptReservationOpen(true)
            console.log(id)
        },
        label: "Foglalás elfogadása",
    },
]
```